# BeautifulSoup doesn't take the full HTML code

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm having some troubles with this code, where I try to take all Pokemon's names from `pokedex.org`. My original code is the following :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://pokedex.org/'
html = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,'lxml')

uls = html.find('ul', attrs = {'id':'monsters-list'})

print(uls.prettify())
```

Then, `uls` should contain some `<li></li>` which themselves contain `<span></span>` where the name is wrapped in. It works quite well taking all the content for the exact 100 first Pokemons, but then it returns me empty `<li></li>` for the 500 others. I've tried different parsers such as `html.parser`, `html5lib` and `lxml` but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is loaded dynamically, therefore `requests` won't support it. We can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page and need scroll page down also.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads). Here is code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://pokedex.org/'
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
webdriver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)

webdriver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5)
html = BeautifulSoup(webdriver.page_source,'lxml')

uls = html.find('ul', attrs = {'id':'monsters-list'})

print(uls.prettify())
```

Output last item :

```
<li style="background: linear-gradient(90deg, #B8B8D0 50%, #A8B820 50%)">
  <button class="monster-sprite sprite-649" type="button">
  </button>
  <span>
   Genesect
  </span>
 </li>
```

Comment: I didn't know this package since I was only dealing with static websites until now. Thank you very much, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the element is being created by JavaScript, but requests can't handle dynamically generated elements by JavaScript.
(correct me if i'm wrong)

I suggest using selenium together with ChromeWebDriver to get the page source,
then you can use BeautifulSoup for parsing.

(Assuming you use chrome browser)

1. visit: [chrome://settings/help](http://chrome://settings/help) and check your chrome version
2. download suitable version of chromewebdriver from official website
   (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)
3. place chromedriver.exe and python file in same directory

finally we get to the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# headless background execution
Options = Options()
Options.headless = True

url = "https://pokedex.org/"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options)
browser.get(url)

html = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')
uls = html.find('ul', attrs={'id': 'monsters-list'})

print(uls.prettify())
```

Comment: I didn't know this package since I was only dealing with static websites until now. Thank you very much, it works fine.